# How to load and process dataset with million columns with Pandas or Pandas-like library?

Tags: python, pandas

I usually find question and discussion about loading dataset with several million rows to python, by using Dask or Pandas chunk-size, but my problem is a bit different. I got millions of columns/features, and only a few thousand records. I found that the data loading time(from csv) with such dataset is absurdly slow, and consume large memory, I have done some benchkmark and sometimes, pandas is even faster than dask!

I tested the case in which I have 1 million rows and 300 columns, I can load it in memory easily, but if I have 300 rows and 1 million columns, then pandas consumes all 64GB RAM and dies.

How can I handle such dataset?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @NickODell see my idea for this in my answer. Please let me know if you think this could be a good idea. I think your answer is a good one though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tested the case in which I have 1 million rows and 300 columns, I can load it in memory easily, but if I have 300 rows and 1 million columns, then pandas consumes all 64GB RAM and dies.
> How can I handle such dataset?

Pandas is built on the assumptions that:

- all of the items in a column are of a common datatype, and
- the number of rows is much larger than the number of columns.

If those assumptions don't hold, then Pandas will be very inefficient.

You can read [these slides](http://www.jeffreytratner.com/slides/pandas-under-the-hood-pydata-seattle-2015.pdf) to understand how Pandas works internally. Essentially, Pandas specializes each column by type, picking the most restrictive type for that column, which allows Pandas to use less memory for each cell. However, if you have few rows and many columns, then the per-column overhead will be very large.

I would suggest that you avoid formatting your data like this. Here is some Python code which can transpose a CSV file without using Pandas:

```py
import csv
def transpose():
    a = zip(*csv.reader(open("test.csv", "rt")))
    csv.writer(open("transposed.csv", "wt")).writerows(a)
```

(On my computer, this takes 300MB for a 100K by 300 CSV file. Compare that to 900MB for opening it in read_csv normally.)

Comment: thank you, in edge case when the transposed dataset is too big to be re-transposed in memory, how should I tackle that?

Comment: @ThanhNguyen Depends on how big it is - The approach I posted above will use 50% of the memory that you would need to hold the whole CSV in memory. So if your CSV is smaller than 128GB, (64GB * 2) you could do it this way. If you want to go bigger, you could try David Erickson's approach, which reads a subset of columns each time. That is less efficient for IO, and CPU, but more memory-efficient. Many approaches could be taken, depending on how big the CSV is.

Answer (score 2):

This was my idea in the comments if you were to use pandas. This is untested, but you could do columns in chunks using `usecols` dynamically. I said `iloc` in comments, but that would still require reading the entire file first, so what I meant was `usecols`. You can just adjust `i` and the number in the range.

```
i = 10
for _ in range(1,4):
    cols = list(range(i-10,i))
    print(cols)
    df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=cols).T
    df.append(df)
    i += 10
df = df.T

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

As you can see you can essentially "chunk"  by columns using this technique.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Very nice, outside-the-box answer. It's worth noting that this answer uses a time-memory tradeoff - you can reduce the memory use, but only by calling read_csv multiple times, which will take longer.